Gaussian processes for Machine Learning, Rasmussen, Exercise 4.3
Problem
Consider the random process $f(x) = \text{erf}(u_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{D}u_j x_j),$ where $u \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$. Show that this non-linear transform of a process with an inhomogeneous linear covariance function has the same covariance function as the $\text{erf}$ neural network. However, note that this process is not a Gaussian process.
The covariance function of the $\text{erf}$ neural network is
$$k_{NN}(x, x') = \frac{2}\pi \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2\tilde{x}^{\intercal}\Sigma \tilde{x}'}{\sqrt{(1 + 2\tilde{x}^\intercal\Sigma \tilde{x})(1 + 2\tilde{x}'^\intercal \Sigma \tilde{x}')}}\right).$$
Attempt at solution
First, I feel like it should be true that $\mathbb{E}_u[f(x)] = 0$. I'm a little stuck about how to show that...it can be shown that
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[f(x)] &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du \\
&= \frac12\left(
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du  + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du 
\right) \\
&= \frac12\left(
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du  +  (-1)^{D+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(-u^\intercal x)p(-u) du 
\right) \\ 
&= \frac12\left(
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du  +  (-1)^{D+2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{D+1}} \text{erf}(u^\intercal x)p(u) du 
\right).
\end{align*}
$$
which seems to imply that $\mathbb{E}[f(x)] = 0$ only when $D$ is odd, which seems unintuitive to me. Did I do something wrong?

The following lemma comes handy:

Lemma. Let $(X, Y)$ be a centered gaussian vector with the covariance matrix $\Sigma = \Bigl( \!\begin{smallmatrix} \Sigma_{XX} & \Sigma_{XY} \\ \Sigma_{XY} & \Sigma_{YY} \end{smallmatrix} \! \Bigr)$. Then
$$ \mathbf{Cov}(\operatorname{erf}(X), \operatorname{erf}(Y)) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\left( \frac{2\Sigma_{XY}}{\sqrt{(1+2\Sigma_{XX})(1+2\Sigma_{YY})}} \right). $$

Now the desired conclusion easily follows by noting that, with $\tilde{x} = (1, x)$ and $\tilde{x}' = (1, x')$, the covariance matrix of $\langle \tilde{x}, u \rangle$ and $\langle \tilde{x}', u\rangle$ is given by
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{x}^{\top}\Sigma\tilde{x} & \tilde{x}^{\top}\Sigma\tilde{x}' \\
\tilde{x}^{\top}\Sigma\tilde{x}' & \tilde{x}'^{\top}\Sigma\tilde{x}'
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Proof of Lemma. We invoke the following observation:

Observation. Let $(X, Y)$ be a bivariate normal vector with the correlation coefficient $\rho$. Then
$$ 4\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0, Y \geq 0) - 1 = \frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin \rho. $$
Proof. Let $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$ denote the standard deviation of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Also, let $\alpha = \arccos \rho$. Then we can write
$$ X = \sigma_X Z, \qquad Y = \sigma_Y (Z \cos \alpha + W \sin \alpha)$$
for some IID standard normal variables $Z$ and $W$. Using this, it is easy to check that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \geq 0, Y \geq 0) = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2\pi}, $$
from which the desired conclusion follows.

Now, let $Z$ and $W$ be standard normal variables such that the three objects, $(X, Y)$, $Z$, and $W$, are mutually independent. Then by a simple algebra, we find that
$$ \operatorname{erf}(x) = \mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{\sqrt{2}x \geq Z\}} - 1]. $$
So by letting $X' = \sqrt{2}X - Z$ and $Y' = \sqrt{2}Y - W$, then $X'$ and $Y'$ are centered gaussian variables with the correlation coefficient $\rho$ given by
$$ \rho
= \frac{\mathbf{Cov}(X', Y')}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(X') \mathbf{Var}(Y')}}
= \frac{2\Sigma_{XY}}{(2\Sigma_{XX} + 1)(2\Sigma_{YY} + 1)}.
$$
Also, we have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{erf}(X)
&= \mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{\sqrt{2}X \geq Z\}} - 1 \mid X, Y] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X' \geq 0\}} - 1 \mid X, Y]
\end{align*}
and similarly,
$$ \operatorname{erf}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{Y' \geq 0\}} - 1 \mid X, Y]. $$
From this, it is easy to check that $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{erf}(X)] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{erf}(Y)] = 0$. (In fact, this follows from a much more elementary argument by noting that $\operatorname{erf}$ is an odd function and the distribution of $u$ is symmetric.) Moreover, by noting that $X'$ and $Y'$ are conditionally independent given $(X, Y)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{erf}(X)\operatorname{erf}(Y)]
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X' \geq 0\}} - 1 \mid X, Y]\mathbb{E}[2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{Y' \geq 0\}} - 1 \mid X, Y]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X' \geq 0\}} - 1)(2 \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{Y' \geq 0\}} - 1)] \\
&= 4\mathbb{P}(X' \geq 0, Y' \geq 0) - 2\mathbb{P}(X' \geq 0) - 2\mathbb{P}(Y' \geq 0) + 1 \\
&= 4\mathbb{P}(X' \geq 0, Y' \geq 0) - 1.
\end{align*}
Therefore the desired claim follows by applying the above observation.

Thank you so much! The re-parametrization of a bivariate Gaussian into linear combinations of normal Gaussians is neat!
